# Unique node id from similar strings with different ids

Tags: java, c#, treeview

I have a list of strings that looks like this (only the structure matters; the fact that they can be split by the underscore):

aaa_bbb_ccc
aaa_bbb_ddd
aaa_bbb_ddd_eee
bbb_ddd_eee

The list is transformed into a tree by creating parent-child relations based on the underscore. For example the tree will have 2 nodes `aaa` and `bbb` then each parent will have one child `bbb` and `ddd` respectively and so on.

Each string has a unique ID (say first line has ID 1, second line ID 2 etc.) but I also need a unique ID for each different node. My idea was to give each node the same ID as the string that produced it. That is `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc` all get ID 1. When the second line is split I can give `ddd` ID 2 but `aaa` and `bbb` cannot have 2 as ID because they have 1 as ID already.

Is there a consistent way so that after transforming the string list into a tree, each node can receive a unique ID? By consistent I mean that building the string back and restoring the string ID from the nodes would not have conflicts because of different IDs. If there is no consistent way, could this approach be considered good practice (assuming that if a node has an ID then it won't be changed with a new one and that the string restoring might not be needed)?

EDIT: I cannot use the text (e.g. `aaa`, `bbb`) as ID because the child `bbb` of `aaa` would end up having the same ID as the parent `bbb` (on the fourth line).

Comment: @RufusL I will try to post some code as soon as I get home. The problem is not about accessing the ID but rather deriving its value from the string ID

Comment: Why can't you use the string value 'aaa', 'bbb' etc as the ID?

Comment: @AshwineeKJha well the problem would be that the child `bbb` of `aaa` would end up having the same ID as the parent `bbb` (on the fourth line)

Comment: Then you probably need to assign a number to each node irrespective of content may be based on pre-order, post-order or in-order traversal. Then use both content and nod number as unique id, i.e id is tuple of (text, node_number). I think any approach of converting a string to a number via some kind of hashing would result in some conflicts.

Comment: @AshwineeKJha I tried that but the order in the tree changes since some nodes get added/removed and so the ID of the same node changes too

Answer (score 0):

i have treeView and the same problem but for my domain i decided to set a increment number form example every node that add to my tree i increment the number and set to the node as id and i have a data value to specify what node is parent of other nodes and for search i use this to data.

but if you want a value for order of nodes i suggest to have id and a second value for order that must fill like this

```
id     value
----------------
1      1-
2      1-2-
3      1-2-3-
4      1-4-
5      5-
```

and you must update this value must change if a parent change at least it's not difficult

it value save order for you too

Comment: While it may work in most cases, the order in the tree changes since some nodes get added/removed and so the ID of the same node changes too

Comment: id as unique name is good and usable but if you but if you a an idea for order of data i suggest you to use a string value that contain parent id, i will edit answer